# SMS Framework - Multiple destination numbers

Tags: rules

I'm using SMS Framework module to send sms from Drupal site; Clickatell is setted as my default gateway. Using Rules module I'm able to notify users via sms when new node is created, but i can only setup one destination number.
Is there anyway to setup mutiple destination number?

A screenshoot of my rule configuration below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am wondering how much do you pay for a sms-message because I'am working on a custom Module to verify Users per sms

Comment: As I already said in question above, I'm using clickatell as gateway to send message so you can check their pricing at https://www.clickatell.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is about D7, you could try to create a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) of those users that you want to send an SMS to.

After you succeeded in creating such view, you can *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions (in the rule you already have in place):

- Load the VBO list of those users.
- Add a loop to perform a Rules Action "send an SMS" (similar to what your current rule already does), for each user contained in your Views results.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".